# Centreon check_snmp returns raw data

Tags: plugins, snmp, nagios

I am supervising a NTP server using Centreon. I am trying to get the System Date through SNMP. Using snmpwalk I identified the correct OID which is HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 (or .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.2.0).

Using snmpget with the numeric OID, I get back the correct value, like this:
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2017-1-19,9:51:25.0,+0:0

Now, back to Centreon. I use the check_snmp plugin with the following command:
./check_snmp -H xx.xx.xx.xx -C xxxxxx -o .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.2.0 -l 'System Date'

The problem is the value returned is in raw form:
SNMP OK - System Date 07 E1 01 13 09 35 01 00 2B 00 00  | 'System Date'=07

I updated nagios-plugins, I tried all the options available, but I cannot get the plugins to return the same thing as my snmpget result.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but you certainly are correct!

I got around the issue during replicating of the issue by simply using `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0` as the oid in `check_snmp`, like this:

```
[nagios@nagios libexec]# ./check_snmp -H hh -C cc -o HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0
SNMP OK - 2017-1-19,9:28:45.0,-6:0 | HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0=2017
```

Where hh and cc are hostname and community string, respectively.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice workaround, didn't think to test with the translated OID :) Thanks!